# getting DHCP ip address from router on Docker

Tags: networking, dhcp, docker

Is it possible to get an DHCP ip address from my router on my a docker, I have tried using bridges and pipeline to no avail and beggining to think im crazy,

TIA

Comment: Take a look through the [docker networking document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) to see if you can find your answer